# React App: I'm not able to click any input field or select any text

Tags: reactjs, html-input

I can't select any text or click on input fields in my React app. I have tried to search similar issue on the internet but can't find any. If anyone has encountered or is familiar with this issue, please advise. I have already tried disabling CSS, disabling packages and transferred it to new react app. Nothing helped.

Video Link: https://vimeo.com/614409488

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Developers and community members need to know exactly what your problem is, what are the things that you have already done to solve your issue and some code! read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question to get a better understanding of stackoverflow questions and guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I have run this command inside the project directory and working fine.

for android

`npx react-native run-android`

for iOS

`npx react-native run-ios`